# Difference between activity handler and view handler android

Tags: android, android-handler

I was trying to send a message to activity handler from a Listview's onItemClick() method of OnItemClickListener.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Handler handler = view.getHandler();
    String data = "MSG DATA";
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(MSG_TYPE, data);
    msg.sendToTarget();
}
```

And I have a handler in activity as

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    int msgId = msg.what;
    Log.d(TAG,"GOT msg : " + msgId);
    }
}
```

But I don't get the message and application crashes.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.view.View$AttachInfo$InvalidateInfo
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3175)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

From documentation for getHandler():

> A handler associated with the thread running the View. This handler can be used to pump events in the UI events queue.

So if the view is created in activity, they both should be on same thread. Why am I getting crash? Are these two different handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are these two different handlers?

They are different `Handler`s attached to the same UI thread `Looper`.

> So if the view is created in activity, they both should be on same thread. Why am I getting crash?

When you do `handler.obtainMessage(MSG_TYPE, data);` it actually sets the `target` to `handler`. So, when you call `msg.sendToTarget();` it sends the message to `View`'s `Handler`, not to `Activity`'s one. You are getting this exception because `View`'s `Handler` doesn't know how to handle that `String`.

Set your `Activity`'s `Handler` as a `target` and you won't get that crash.

Comment: Thank you for clarification :)

Comment: Just curious, how does one access the `Activity`'s `Handler`?